# Date operations PHP and SQL, getting past year if i subtract months

Tags: php, sql, addition, subtraction

Good day all! I'm new on this beautiful site. I would like to ask a question about date subraction using SQL squery.
I wrote this :

```
SELECT COALESCE (SUM(numero_ore),0) as totOra
FROM ore_lavorate
WHERE id_dip = '$id' AND MONTH(`data_rif`) = ".$stringa."
```

data_rif is a date field and $stringa is a number that i subtract from this date. It works fine but if my month is january and $stringa is '-1' it takes same december but from the same year.

Better explained if data_rif is 2020-02-01 and $stringa is -3 my result is 2020-12-01. How can i get december but from the past year?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) Take a look at [mcve] too.

Comment: I'm using MARIADB.
I expect to have a table with all result from ore_lavorate where data_rif (date field) are between 1st and last day of the month.

Comment: Thanks! I did like this
                            $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ore_lavorate WHERE data_rif >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL ".$_POST['mese']."  MONTH) AND data_rif <= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL ".$_POST['mese']." -1  MONTH) AND id_dip = '$id' ORDER BY data_rif ");